# Wordpress - remove wp-post-image class

Tags: wordpress

Long story short I am finding that when some posts are shared with reddit, it pulls the wrong image. It pulls the image from the sidebar, and I think it is doing this because the thumbnail has wp-post-image as its class and therefor it THINKS that that is the post image but it is just part of the sidebar...

how can I get it to remove that class from the function the_post_image so that I don't have to worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'Facebook Like Thumbnail' plugin? I had the same problem with one of my sites & it was able to fix the issue. http://blog.ashfame.com/2011/02/wordpress-plugin-fix-facebook-like-thumbnail/